# hive : full outer join result has repetition rows

Tags: hive

every table has remove validation row key, sql like

```
select count(*)
from
    dw_rk.f_t_rk_dzxx tb1 full
                              outer join (
        select
            s1.gmsfhm as sfzhm,
            s1.sjjzd_dzbm,
            s1.qxqc,
            s1.xzjd,
            s1.qxc,
            s1.pcs,
            s1.jws,
            s1.dm,
            s1.mph,
            s1.xqqc,
            s1.lfmc,
            s1.dy,
            s1.fh,
            s1.dzqc,
            from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:dd:ss') as d_timestamp,
            'gaj' as d_deptname,
            'f_s_zw_gaj_ldzh_syrk_rkjbxxb' as d_tabname
        from
            (
                select
                    t0.gmsfhm,
                    t0.sjjzd_dzbm,
                    case
                        when t2.qxmc is null then t1.qxmc
                        else t2.qxmc
                        end as qxqc,
                    t1.xzjd as xzjd,
                    case
                        when t3.qxc is null then t1.qxc
                        else t3.qxc
                        end as qxc,
                    t1.pcs as pcs,
                    t1.jwqmc as jws,
                    t1.dm as dm,
                    t1.mph as mph,
                    t1.xqmc as xqqc,
                    t1.lfmc as lfmc,
                    t1.dy as dy,
                    t1.fh as fh,
                    t1.dzqc as dzqc,
                    row_number() over (
                        partition by t0.gmsfhm
                        order by
                            t0.gxsj,
                            t0.rksj desc
                        ) as num
                from
                    dws.f_s_zw_gaj_ldzh_syrk_rkjbxxb t0
                        left join dws.f_s_zw_ldzh_bzdz_dzjbxxb t1 on t0.sjjzd_dzbm = t1.dzbh
                        left join (
                        select
                            distinct ssxqbm,
                                     qxmc
                        from
                            dws.f_s_zw_ldzh_bzdz_dzjbxxb
                    ) t2 on t0.sjjzd_ssxqdm = t2.ssxqbm
                        left join (
                        select
                            distinct qxcbh,
                                     qxc
                        from
                            dws.f_s_zw_ldzh_bzdz_dzjbxxb
                    ) t3 on t0.sjjzd_sqjcwhdm = t3.qxcbh
                where
                    t0.gmsfhm is not null
            ) s1
        where
                s1.num = 1
    ) tb2 on tb1.sfzhm = tb2.sfzhm;
```

explain is

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-7 is a root stage
"  Stage-12 depends on stages: Stage-7, Stage-13 , consists of Stage-15, Stage-3"
  Stage-15 has a backup stage: Stage-3
  Stage-11 depends on stages: Stage-15
"  Stage-10 depends on stages: Stage-3, Stage-8, Stage-11 , consists of Stage-14, Stage-4"
  Stage-14 has a backup stage: Stage-4
  Stage-9 depends on stages: Stage-14
"  Stage-5 depends on stages: Stage-4, Stage-9"
  Stage-1 depends on stages: Stage-5
  Stage-4
  Stage-3
  Stage-8 is a root stage
  Stage-16 is a root stage
  Stage-13 depends on stages: Stage-16
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1
```

when I create middle table to get table2`s data,result is right

Comment: everyt ables has million rows, max keys num is alse million,but after join get about two millions rows